# Exporting classes with a constructor vs. no constructor

Tags: class, typescript, constructor, angular, export

Using Angular2 with typescript. Ran into this question about constructors and classes I couldn't find an answer to.

So I was trying to figure out the difference between these two pieces of code. Not sure if one is better to use in practice. Thanks

```
export class ONE {
     id: number;
     name: string;
}
```

and

```
export class TWO {

  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    ) {  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None. Well apart from the parameter initialization of course.

You can easily check that by looking at the generated code.

```js
var ONE = (function () {
    function ONE() {
    }
    return ONE;
}());
var TWO = (function () {
    function TWO(id, name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    return TWO;
}());
```

You can easily check that in the TypeScript [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20ONE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TWO%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20id%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20%7B%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).